# What do these Web Essentials options do?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, web-essentials

I see these menu options for my asp.net project beneath the Web Essentials menu:

```
Create solution settings
Create color palette
Create markdown stylesheet
```

The official site for Web Essentials doesn't seem to be too forthcoming about just what these options do, or why. Can somebody give me the skinny?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Create solution settings** - sets the settings file per solution.
Reason: Many of the options affect the generation of code. Those options should be able to be shared alongside the solution file so all members of a team automatically use the same settings. Also, if the settings are stored alongside the solution, they can be checked into version control.

**Create color palette** -  WE reads and generates UI that shows your site's color pallete, from there you could just pick the colors instead of having to try to remember what the color codes are.

**Create markdown stylesheet** - I think this one is used for code samples, allows to specify a custom CSS file for the Markdown preview pane

Comment: So does it take the settings from the user who selected the "Create solution settings" option, and then that user can czech it into source control, and everybody thereafter uses his settings? Or does it generate a generic set of settings for all to use?

Comment: Regarding "Create color palette": from where is that site-specific color picker thereafter accessible?

Comment: That's right, the settings are generated for the user that selected the  solution settings, and can be shared by other users.

Comment: I never used the color palette option, but I guess you can use it as   any other CSS

Comment: Oh, I get it; the color palette creates a CSS snippet or file. Thanks.